# How to delete an accepted answer in stack overflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, accepted-answer

In Stack Overflow I answered one question asked by someone. Someone accepted my answer as the correct answer. But after that I got 4 downvotes, so I decided to delete my answer.

But, I am unable to delete an accepted answer. I checked FAQ too. How can I delete the accepted answer?

Comment: You can ask the question author to unaccept your answer, if that happens, you can delete it.

Comment: You can't do it yourself. If you can improve it then do it by editing otherwise if you agree that it's plain wrong then flag it for moderator attention choosing "other" and explaining the situation.

Comment: BTW guess you mean [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8147041/447356)?

Comment: If its http://stackoverflow.com/a/8147041, I added a delete vote. Just 2 to go.

Comment: Problem solved.

Comment: its now deleted

Comment: i was wondering why my reputation downed by 5 and it doesn't showed any details...now i got it...thank you.

Answer (score 14):

Flag it for moderator attention and explain that you want your answer deleted. In case of a negatively-voted answer the moderators will likely follow your request and delete your answer.